# share url and webpage title using Automator

Tags: mac, automator

I would like to know how to share url and webpage title by doing the following step.

1. Select URL in Safari
2. Right click and choose `Share via Email`
3. Automator will open the email program, put the title of a web page as a subject, and put the URL in the message body.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'cgi'

url = STDIN.read.strip
curl = `curl -s -L #{url}`
title = CGI.unescapeHTML(curl.scan(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m)[0][0].strip)
mail = "mailto:?subject=#{CGI.escapeHTML(title)}&body=#{CGI.escapeHTML(url)}"
system("open", mail)
```

1. Open Automator and choose the *Service* template
2. Add a *Run Shell Script* action, and select `/usr/bin/ruby` in the *Shell* dropdown
3. Paste the script and save